# Treeview contextmenu not working command in HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a TreeView, which works fine. Within this I have a context menu, which works fine, except for the command which is the issue at hand.

The main parts, I think are here:

```
<TreeView x:Name="ScenesTreeView01" Grid.Column="0" Width="Auto" Background="AliceBlue" ItemsSource="{Binding Scenes}" SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged" BorderThickness="0">
        <TreeView.DataContext>
            <viewModels:ScenesViewModel />
        </TreeView.DataContext>
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    <GradientStopCollection>
                        <GradientStop Color="#F7D073" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#F1A62F" Offset="1"/>
                    </GradientStopCollection>
                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="SceneLevel">
                            <MenuItem Header="Add selected character" Command="{Binding AddSelectedCharacter}"/>
            </ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="CharacterLevel">
                <MenuItem Header="Character Level"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </TreeView.Resources>
```

And here:

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Characters}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ContextMenu="{StaticResource SceneLevel}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SceneName}"></TextBlock>

                        <Image Source="{StaticResource ImgBook1}" Margin="0,0,5,0" Width="32" Height="32"/>

                </StackPanel>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="LightBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2" CornerRadius="5,5,5,5">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3" ContextMenu="{StaticResource CharacterLevel}">

                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Levenim MT" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="50" Text="{Binding FirstName}"></TextBlock>

                                <Image Source="{Binding ImgIcon}" Margin="2" Width="32" Height="32"/>

                        </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

The second one's not really important, but it shows where the two context menus are used. As I said, they appear as expected.

As for my command... I have used commands before in this project and use them at other points in this project. I use MicroMVVM's 'RelayCommand' to create them and they have worked fine so far.

The command in question sits inside the 'ScenesViewModel' class which is, as you might imagine, a view model.

The code for the command is here:

```
void AddSelectedCharacterExecute()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Adding character");
        return;
    }

    bool CanAddSelectedCharacterExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public ICommand AddSelectedCharacter { get { return new RelayCommand(AddSelectedCharacterExecute, CanAddSelectedCharacterExecute); } }
```

It doesn't really do much at the moment, but I can't even get the MessageBox to appear. Break points show that code is not reached when I click on the context menu item.

Have I missed something obvious here? Or is it something in the process? A vague thought is that, because the ViewModel is attached to the TreeView, the TreeView.Resources might not know about it yet? I'm clutching at straws I guess.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since you are in a `DataTemplate`, the `DataContext` moves. Try to bind your ContextMenu with `RelativeSource` -> `FindAncestor` -> `TreeView` -> DataContext.Command

Comment: Can this be achieved in XAML? I've never used the arrow as an operator there. I know you can bind to RelativeSource, but if I press the period key, the options I get do not include 'FindAncestor'. Is this how you meant I should do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to bind to a property of the `ScenesViewModel` using an `{x:Reference}`:

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    ...
    <ContextMenu x:Key="SceneLevel">
        <MenuItem Header="Add selected character" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.AddSelectedCharacter, Source={x:Reference ScenesTreeView01}}"/>
    </ContextMenu>
    ...
</TreeView.Resources>
```

Comment: Nice idea! Havent thought of the `x:Reference`. Learnt something new! Thank you sir :)

Answer (score 1):

Forget my comment. My brain was somewhere else.

To do what you want, you have to do some hackish stuff, since a `ContextMenu` is not part of the VisualTree.

Following you find a small example:

#### Xaml

```
<Grid>
   <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Scenes}" x:Name="rootView">
       <TreeView.Resources>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="SceneLevel" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget.Tag}">
                <MenuItem Header="Add selected character" Command="{Binding AddSelectedCharacter}"/>
            </ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="CharacterLevel">
                <MenuItem Header="Character Level"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </TreeView.Resources>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Characters}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ContextMenu="{StaticResource SceneLevel}" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}, Path=DataContext}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="LightBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2" CornerRadius="5,5,5,5">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3" ContextMenu="{StaticResource CharacterLevel}">
                                <TextBlock FontFamily="Levenim MT" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="50" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

#### Code-Behind

```
 public partial class Window2 {

    public Window2() {
      InitializeComponent();

      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var s = new Scene() { Name = "Scene " + i };
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
          var c = new Character() { Name = "Character " + j };
          s.Characters.Add(c);
        }
        this.Scenes.Add(s);
      }

      this.DataContext = this;
    }

    void AddSelectedCharacterExecute(object param) {
      MessageBox.Show("Adding character");
      return;
    }

    public ICommand AddSelectedCharacter {
      get {
        return new RelayCommand(AddSelectedCharacterExecute, o => true);
      }
    }

    private List<Scene> _scenes = new List<Scene>();
    public List<Scene> Scenes => this._scenes;

  }

  public class Scene {
    public Scene() {
      this.Characters = new List<Character>();
    }

    public string Name {
      get; set;
    }

    public List<Character> Characters {
      get;
    }

  }

  public class Character {

    public string Name {
      get; set;
    }

  }
```

As you can see, i abuse the Stackpanels Tag as Placeholder for the DataContext. Now i have access in the ContextMenu to the PlacementTarget (which is the StackPanel). After this workaround, the rest should be simple.

Hope this helps! Cheers